# Using a command object chain command with a view

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am using grails v2.3.3 and I am trying to work with a set of instances of a command object across two actions.

In the first action I create the set of command object instances which I then display in a view to be edited.

I then use a link in the view to submit this data to another action in the same controller that needs to access the updated set of command object instances.

I have looked at the 'chain' command which enables command objects to be accessible across different actions but it seems to offer a direct link from one action to another without the option to display a view and enable some user interface.

I cannot see how to implement this with a view in order to update the contents of these command object instances which then get sent to the 2nd action to be processed.

I have the command object set to a 'session' scope and am surprised that by default it is not accessible across all actions of the controller anyway - what does the scope mean?

-mike

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of doing this is to recreate the command objects from posted form data in the second action. This means that the view's form must include all of the fields of the command object either as visible (editable) or hidden (pass through) input fields. Grails command object binding support will automatically populate new command objects if you place them as parameters to the action. Also, you can always manually construct new command object instances using the "params" map values which contains all of the posted form fields.

See the sections on Command Objects and Data Binding in the Grails manual for details and examples.

Comment: Steve Hole - There is a complication and that is that the contents of the command object setup in the 1st action consists of a list of files (of type MultiPartfile from an html multiple file form/ input tag. I am having difficulty referencing the files to upload them in the 2nd action - is there going to be an issue doing MultiPartFile requests (such as getFile()) across actions in this way?

Comment: On passing the set of command objects (two in this case) to the 2nd action I am having problems recasting them in the original CO form. If I print them out as part of the params I get: `flUp:[vidplay.UploadFiles@1162400f, vidplay.UploadFiles@495ba1b3]`. If I try and recast them as the original command object in the 2nd action by looping through the two object:  `for (UploadFiles uP in params.flUp){}`. I get a GroovyCastException error: **Cannot cast object 'vidplay.UploadFiles@1162400f' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'vidplay.UploadFiles'**. Any suggestions? -mike